# TwoWayView(extends AdapterView) calculates its height based on the first element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapterview

I have a TwoWayView containing elements with icon, TextView below the icon (item title) and RatingBar below the Text View.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:id="@+id/group_layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="3dip">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/group_title"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_text"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is an item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/group_item"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_main_icon"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </ImageView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/is_new_icon"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_new"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="110dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end">
    </TextView>
    <include layout="@layout/rating_bar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Item title can be of one or two lines. Everything works good if the first element's title has two lines:

[image: Correct]

But if the first element's title is single-line TwoWayView's height is calculated based on it - so for another elements with two-lines title the rating bar will be truncated:

[image: Wrong]

So as you can see the rating bar is truncated on the second element because the height of TwoWayView is calculated based on the height of the first element.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

**UPD:** here is the code for my TwoWayView. There is nothing special:

```
TwoWayView profileListView = (TwoWayView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list);
profileListView.setAdapter(new ApplicationGroupAdapter(profilesToDisplay, details, this.getActivity()));
```

Comment: Show the code for your `TwoWayView`.

Comment: I updated my post, but there is nothing special in my code

Comment: I did not realize it was a [library](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) that you were using.

Comment: Manually setting appropriate height for TextView so that it will allocated enough space to show 2 lines will be a solution.